# R Raster: Calculation Distance from each grid cell to other raster cells within a radius

Tags: r, loops, foreach, distance, raster

I have a raster object that contains numeric values and NA's and I want to know the distance from each raster cell with values to the other numeric cells within a radius. The result is a matrix/raster that contains the summed distance for each numeric raster cell that are not NA. The cells not considered get NA's. The problem now is that the calculation takes a relatively long time because I have to make a loop over all raster cells to test if they are numeric, and then calculating the distances. Afterwards, I have to select all raster cells which are numeric, and select all numeric cells within a certain radius, as the accCost function does not consider cells with NA's for calulating the distances. Is there a faster way to calculate the summed distances of raster cells within a certain radius?

First, I have a raster, which I have to modify, because I only want to know the summed distance of cells that lie within a specific area. Since the accCost function does not consider NA's, I need to give them a value. Then I define the cores for the "foreach" function. As I use the "accCost" function to calculate the distances from one raster cell to the others, I need to make some default settings and calulating the xy coordinates of the cells. To select the distances which are not NA's, I make a boolena query.
Then I loop over each raster cell to test, if they have a certain value. When yes, then I calculate the distance to each grid cell with the "accCost" function. Then I subset the resulting raster. Otherwise, the raster cell gets NA's.

```
#load library
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
library(gdistance)
library(raster)

#Create a raster
mraster<-matrix(nrow=15,ncol = 15)
mraster[c(5,10,9,15,13,5),c(4,8,9,7,7,15)]<-1
builtupraster<-raster(mraster, xmn=1, xmx=1500, ymn=1, ymx=1500)
proj4string(builtupraster) <- CRS("+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.952405555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
builtupraster[is.na(builtupraster)]<-0

#define parallel function
cores<-detectCores()
cl<-makeCluster(cores-2)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

#calculate the distance between cells fast
r <- builtupraster
r2 <- transition(r, transitionFunction = function(x){1}, directions = 16)
r2 <- geoCorrection(r2,  scl=FALSE)
siedlungsfl<-as.matrix(r>0)

xcord<-xFromCol(r,1:ncol(r))
ycord<-yFromRow(r,1:nrow(r))

testrow<-1:nrow(r)
testcol<-1:ncol(r)

distmat<-foreach(row= testrow, .combine = "rbind" ,.packages = "gdistance") %:%
 foreach(col= testcol, .combine="c",.packages = "gdistance") %dopar%{
 if(r[row,col]>0){
   d <- accCost(r2,c(xcord[row],ycord[col]))
   d2 <- d[which(siedlungsfl)]
   d3 <- d2[d2<=2000]
   d4 <- sum(sqrt(2*d3+1)-1)/length(d3)+(sqrt(0.97428*30+1.46)-0.996249)

 } else{

   d4 <- NA 

 }
}
```

The result is like: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgiae.png)

Comment: you should provide a small, and as simple as possible, reproducible example with some input data (generated with code) and correct output data.

Comment: @RobertHijmans I have now adapted the code with an example. I added the ouput result as an image file. Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your script --- removing the parallelization, so that it is easier to optimize. I have removed a loop and an if statement, and made some other changes; that could help a bit, but perhaps not very much.

```
library(gdistance)

r <- raster(nrow=15,ncol = 15, xmn=1, xmx=1500, ymn=1, ymx=1500, vals=0, crs = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.952405555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m"
)
r[c(5,10,9,15,13,5),c(4,8,9,7,7,15)] <- 1

tr <- transition(r, transitionFunction = function(x){1}, directions = 16)
tr <- geoCorrection(tr,  scl=FALSE)

cells <- Which(r > 0, cells=TRUE)
xy <- xyFromCell(r, cells)

constant <- sqrt(0.97428 * 30 + 1.46) - 0.996249
d <- rep(NA, length(cells))
for(i in 1:length(cells)) {
    dst <- accCost(tr, xy[i,])[cells]
    dst <- dst[dst <= 1000] # 2000 is too high for this example
    d[i] <- mean(sqrt(2 * dst + 1) - 1)
}

result <- raster(r)
result[cells] <- d + constant
plot(result)
text(result)
```

Another, probably *slower*, approach could be something like this:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=15,ncol = 15, xmn=1, xmx=1500, ymn=1, ymx=1500, crs = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.952405555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m"
)
r[c(5,10,9,15,13,5),c(4,8,9,7,7,15)] <- 1
d <- distance(r)

cells <- Which(r > 0, cells=TRUE)
b <- buffer(SpatialPoints(xyFromCell(r, cells)), 1000, dissolve=FALSE)
e <- extract(d, b, fun=sum)

result2 <- raster(r)
result2[cells] <- e
plot(result2)
text(result2)
```

The results are not the same, because I sum distances (per your description) whereas you do `constant + mean(sqrt(2 * dst + 1) - 1)`